# Azure Data Factory - copy activity reference what was copied

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I created a pipeline in ADF, that has a copy activity, copying the data from SQL Server to a REST endpoint. I have no control over the REST endpoint, the data just gets posted there.

The source configured as a query, where its source primary key has nothing to do with an ID on the target server. When the data is posted, the target generates their own unique ID:

[image]

Now, I have a requirement to do something else (call a webhook) on the target server once the data is posted there, and need to have a reference to the actual records that were created. Can I get some help in understanding how I can reference the actual items that were just copied and posted? Not the whole list that is on the target.

So, for example, if 3 items were copied and on the target their IDs were generated as 111, 112 and 113, what can I use to get records with those IDs only? Again, those IDs were generated on the target, they did not come form source. The columns that come from source, either do not exist on the target as fields, or they can be duplicated in other existing records. Only generated IDs are unique.

I only know that copy activity reports the number of items copied.  But I need some reference ... to the data created.

Comment: Currently, its not possible to achieve your requirement with copy activity as it won't give the required information. You should have a REST API for your necessary information and call that from ADF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Agreed with @Rakesh Govindula it's not possible to achieve your requirement with copy activity.**

Regretfully, when the data is posted to the destination server, you are unable to obtain the precise records that were produced there using only the built-in features of Azure Data Factory's Copy Activity. This is because Copy Activity lacks built-in capability for tracking particular records on the destination side and instead concentrates on transferring data from a source to a destination.

You'll probably need to put in place a unique solution in order to accomplish your objective. such as querying the intended REST API and maybe filtering the most recent items with a different identification or date. You may then carry out other operations, such triggering a webhook, after you have retrieved the freshly produced data.